# Function defined correctly?

Tags: python, function, probability-distribution

I have a pdf defined as P(r, t). I am trying to define the pdf in python, but am new to the program and am unsure if I correctly defined it. Here is the pdf I am trying to define.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y96Mi.png)

```
from scipy.special import gamma as G

def A(gamma, d):
return np.power(G((d + 2) / gamma) / (G(d / gamma)), (gamma / 2)) 

def B(gamma, d): 
return np.log(gamma * np.power(G((d + 2) / gamma), (d / 2)) / np.power(G(1 / gamma), ((d + 2) / 2)))

def dispersion(gamma, d, t, D):
return np.power((D * t), (2 / gamma)) * g(gamma, d)

def pdf(gamma, d, r, t, D): 
return (1 / np.power(dispersion(gamma, d, t, D), (d / 2))) * np.exp((-A(gamma, d) * np.power((r / np.sqrt(g(gamma, d))), gamma)) + B(gamma, d))
```

I am trying to plot the pdf, but I keep getting an error, so I want to confirm what I have above is correct before I try to move on. Any help would be appreciated! Also, I use G for the gamma function, and gamma to denote the gamma variable.

Where the error is coming from: I created a sample 100x1000 and I let gamma=2 and d=1 for simplicity

```
def pdf(gamma, d, r, t, D): 
return (1 / np.power(dispersion(gamma, d, t, D), (d / 2))) * np.exp((-A(gamma, d) * np.power((r / np.sqrt(g(gamma, d))), gamma)) + B(gamma, d))

r = range(100)
t = range(1000)
gamma = 2
d = 1
D = 2
p = pdf(gamma, d, r, t, D)
plt.plot(r, p)
plt.show()

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'range'
```

Comment: Please post the full error.

Comment: My error is coming from the fact that I did not define my variables when I am trying to plot my pdf, however I am not sure what the support of the pdf is.

Comment: If you don't show the error and the code that causes the error, then no one will be able to help you.

Comment: My initial question was simply if my defined functions were correct, however if they are then I am not sure how to plot my pdf.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in `range` function doesn't support the multiplication operation. Instead you want to use a `numpy` `array`, which you can create in this case by using the `arange()` function.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def pdf(gamma, d, r, t, D): 
    return (1 / np.power(dispersion(gamma, d, t, D), (d / 2))) * np.exp((-A(gamma, d) * np.power((r / np.sqrt(g(gamma, d))), gamma)) + B(gamma, d))

r = np.arange(100)
t = np.arange(1000)
gamma = 2
d = 1
D = 2
p = pdf(gamma, d, r, t, D)
plt.plot(r, p)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I had used the code for a similar plot and so I didn't realize that was my error. Thank you!